# Create and Get Session in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Currently I am  working with Grails. I tried to create and get session in a Grails controller:

```
if (user) {
    session.user = "user"
    flash.message = "Hallo ${user.fullName}!!!!!"
    println(session.user)
    redirect(action: "login")  
}
```

But its failed to create and get.

Comment: What does _"but its failed to create and get"_ mean?

Answer (score 0):

About the session object in Grails, try the following official document: 
[http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html][1]

So, try :

```
session["user"] = "John"
asset "John" == session.user
```